# Hibernate: “Field 'id' doesn't have a default value”

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Project working fine when I try to Insert the data using Java JPA mapping, but getting this error when using .hbm.xml mapping:

```
Hibernate: insert into mytable (name, pwd) values (?, ?)
Oct 14, 2020 6:22:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
ERROR: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
could not execute statement
```

.hbm.xml code of the Project:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name = "com.Hibernet.HibernetUsingMaven2.Person" table = "mytable">
      <meta attribute = "class-description">
         This class contains the person detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name = "id" type = "int" column = "id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name = "name" column = "name" type = "string"/>
      <property name = "pwd" column = "pwd" type = "string"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Java Code of the Project:

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       Person person1=new Person();
       person1.setPwd("Jagbir Singh");
       person1.setId(3);
       person1.setName("jagbir singh");
       Configuration con=new Configuration();
       con.configure();
       SessionFactory sf=con.buildSessionFactory();
       Session session=sf.openSession();
       Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
       session.save(person1);
       tx.commit();
       session.close();
    }
```

Comment: Is this a new project? If so, you're using very old APIs and should prefer the modern ones. What version of Hibernate?

Comment: Yes, it is a new project. 
 Hibernate Version: 5.4.21. 
Okay, I check for any changes in the code. I am just following one youtube video.
Thx - chrylis

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the mapping, it's about your data definition on the SQL side. The `CREATE TABLE` statement, in other words. You didn't bother specifying a default value for the `id` field, and it cannot be null, therefore, the SQL Server you are using is telling you that INSERT statement cannot be executed as written because it violates a constraint (the `id` field has no value, and it must have one).

The fix is to toss the database and fix the CREATE TABLE statement, or use an `ALTER TABLE` statement. Most likely your intent was for `id` to be an auto-sequence primary key style field, in which case junking the table entirely and recreating it is certainly simpler. If you can't, make a sequence, add a constraint - I can't give you specifics because each DB engine has somewhat different syntax for how to do this properly.

Hibernate can generate the CREATE TABLE statement for you, but this is generally not advised (it just doesn't work in practice; from time to time you want to migrate your data structures a bit, add columns and such, and you can't really rhyme that with the notion of 'here is a java class; please create a table that looks just like it') - note that hibernate themselves advise against this.

If you need help with the create table stuff, ask a new SO question with the appropriate tag (for example, `postgresql`), and paste the CREATE TABLE statement you do have along with the question: "How do I make the `id` field the primary key, and auto-counting". Or just search the web, it's a very common task.

Comment: I know what is the meaning of "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"
But If I use this mapping methodology instead of  .hbm.xml mapping the application is working fine.

So I think the problem is with the mapping only. 

`
@Entity

@Table(name="mytable")

public class Person {

 public Person() {}
 
 @Id
 @Column(name="id")
 private int id;
 @Column(name="name")
 private String name;
 @Column(name="pwd")
 private String pwd;
`

Comment: First hit on google, @AkashVaid: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-use-auto-incremented-column-primary-key/